# Design pattern for relational and optional parameters?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I am to build a class that accepts a series of inputs via the constructor method, then perform a calculation with `calculate()` using these parameters. The trick here is that these parameters might be available sometimes and other times might not. There however, is a given equation between the variables, such that the missing ones can be calculated from the equations. Here is an example:

I know that:

```
a = b * c - d 
c = e/f
```

I am to calculate always `a+b+c+d+e+f`

Here is what I have so far:

```
class Calculation:
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    for parameter, value in kwargs.items():
      setattr(self, '_'.format(parameter), value)

  @property
  def a(self):
    try:
      return self._a  
    except AttributeError:
      return self._b * self._c - self._d


  @property
  def b(self):
    try:
      return self._b  
    except AttributeError:
      return (self._a + self._d) / self._c

... // same for all a,b,c,d,e,f 

  def calculate(self):
    return sum(self.a+self.b+self.c+self.d+self.e+self.f)
```

then use as:

```
  c = Calculation(e=4,f=6,b=7,d=2)
  c.calculate()
```

however, some other time might have other variables like:
      c = Calculation(b=5,c=6,d=7,e=3,f=6)
      c.calculate()

My question is: What would be a good design pattern to use in my case? So far, it seems a bit redundant to make a `@property` for all variables. The problem it must solve is to accept any variables (minimum for which calculation is possible) and based on the equation I have, figure out the rest, needed for calculation.

Comment: If there is no setter for any of these values, I would just precompute the missing ones in `__init__` and not bother with the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good candidate for the **getattr** function.  You can store the keyword arguments directly in the class and use that dictionary to either return a known parameter as attribute or infer an unspecified value "on the fly" based on other formulas that you know of:

```
class Calculation:
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      self.params   = kwargs
      self.inferred = {
          "a"     : lambda: self.b * self.c - self.d,
          "c"     : lambda: self.e / self.f,
          "result": lambda: self.a+self.b+self.c+self.d+self.e+self.f
          }

  def __getattr__(self, name):
      if name in self.params:
          return self.params[name]
      if name in self.inferred:
          value = self.inferred[name]()
          self.params[name] = value
          return value

r = Calculation(b=1,d=3,e=45,f=9).result
print(r) # 65.0 (c->45/9->5, a->1*5-3->2)
```

*Note that, if you have very complicated calculations for some of the parameters, you can use functions of the class as the implementation of the lambdas in the self.inferred dictionary.*

If you're going to use this pattern for many formulas, you might want to centralize the boilerplate code in a base class.  This will reduce the work needed for new calculation classes to only having to implement the inferred() function.:

```
class SmartCalc:

  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      self.params   = kwargs

  def __getattr__(self, name):
      if name in self.params:
          return self.params[name]
      if name in self.inferred():
          value = self.inferred()[name]()
          self.params[name] = value
          return value

class Calculation(SmartCalc):

    def inferred(self):
        return {
                 "a"     : lambda: self.b * self.c - self.d,
                 "b"     : lambda: (self.a+self.d)/self.c,
                 "c"     : lambda: self.e / self.f,
                 "d"     : lambda: self.c * self.b - self.a,
                 "e"     : lambda: self.f * self.c,
                 "f"     : lambda: self.e / self.c,
                 "result": lambda: self.a+self.b+self.c+self.d+self.e+self.f
               }
```

With enough content in inferred(), you can even use this approach to obtain any value from a combination of the others:

```
valueF = Calculation(a=2,b=1,c=5,d=3,e=45,result=65).f
print(valueF) # 9.0
```

**EDIT**

If you want to make this even more sophisticated, you can improve **getattr** to allow specification of dependencies in the inferred() dictionary.

For example:

```
class SmartCalc:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.params   = kwargs

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self.params:
            return self.params[name]
        if name in self.inferred():
            calc  = self.inferred()[name]
            if isinstance(calc,dict):
                for names,subCalc in calc.items():
                    if isinstance(names,str): names = [names]
                    if all(name in self.params for name in names):
                        calc = subCalc; break
            value = calc()
            self.params[name] = value
            return value

import math
class BodyMassIndex(SmartCalc):

    def inferred(self):
        return {
                  "heightM"      : { "heightInches":     lambda: self.heightInches * 0.0254,
                                     ("bmi","weightKg"): lambda: math.sqrt(self.weightKg/self.bmi),
                                     ("bmi","weightLb"): lambda: math.sqrt(self.weightKg/self.bmi)
                                   }, 
                  "heightInches" : lambda: self.heightM / 0.0254,
                  "weightKg"     : { "weightLb":             lambda: self.weightLb / 2.20462,
                                     ("bmi","heightM"):      lambda: self.heightM**2*self.bmi,
                                     ("bmi","heightInches"): lambda: self.heightM**2*self.bmi
                                   },
                  "weightLb"     : lambda: self.weightKg * 2.20462,
                  "bmi"          : lambda: self.weightKg / (self.heightM**2)
               }

bmi = BodyMassIndex(heightM=1.75,weightKg=130).bmi
print(bmi) # 42.44897959183673

height = BodyMassIndex(bmi=42.45,weightKg=130).heightInches
print(height) # 68.8968097135968  (1.75 Meters)
```

**EDIT2**

A similar class could be designed to process formulas expressed as text.  This would allow a basic form of term solver using a newton-raphson iterative approximation (at least for 1 degree polynomial equations):

```
class SmartFormula:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.params        = kwargs
        self.moreToSolve   = True
        self.precision     = 0.000001
        self.maxIterations = 10000

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        self.resolve()
        if name in self.params: return self.params[name]

    def resolve(self):
        while self.moreToSolve:
            self.moreToSolve = False
            for formula in self.formulas():
                param = formula.split("=",1)[0].strip()
                if param in self.params: continue
                if "?" in formula:
                    self.useNewtonRaphson(param)
                    continue
                try: 
                    exec(formula,globals(),self.params)
                    self.moreToSolve = True
                except: pass

    def useNewtonRaphson(self,name):
        for formula in self.formulas():
            source,calc = [s.strip() for s in formula.split("=",1)]
            if name   not in calc: continue
            if source not in self.params: continue            
            simDict = self.params.copy()
            target  = self.params[source]
            value   = target
            try:
                for _ in range(self.maxIterations):                    
                    simDict[name] = value
                    exec(formula,globals(),simDict)
                    result        = simDict[source]
                    resultDelta   = target-result
                    value        += value*resultDelta/result/2
                    if abs(resultDelta) < self.precision/2 : 
                        self.params[name] = round(simDict[name]/self.precision)*self.precision
                        self.moreToSolve  = True
                        return

            except: continue
```

With this approach the BodyMassIndex calculator would be easier to read:

```
import math
class BodyMassIndex(SmartFormula):

    def formulas(self):
        return [
                 "heightM      = heightInches * 0.0254",
                 "heightM      = ?",  # use Newton-Raphson solver.  
                 "heightInches = ?",
                 "weightKg     = weightLb / 2.20462",
                 "weightKg     = heightM**2*bmi",
                 "weightLb     = ?",
                 "bmi          = weightKg / (heightM**2)"
               ]
```

This lets you obtain/use terms for which the calculation formula is not explicitly stated in the list (e.g. heightInches computed from heightM which is computed from bmi and weightKg):

```
height = BodyMassIndex(bmi=42.45,weightKg=130).heightInches
print(height) # 68.8968097135968  (1.75 Meters)
```

*Note: The formulas are expressed as text and executed using eval() which may be much slower than the other solution.   Also, the Newton-Raphson algorithm is OK for linear equations but has its limitations for curves that have a mix of positive and negative slopes. For example, I had to include the `weightKg = heightM**2*bmi` formula because obtaining `weightKg` based on `bmi = weightKg/(heightM**2)` needs to solve a `y = 1/x^2` equation which Newton-Raphson can't seem to handle.*

Here's an example using your original problem:

```
class OP(SmartFormula):

    def formulas(self):
        return [
                  "a = b * c - d",
                  "b = ?",
                  "c = e/f",
                  "d = ?",
                  "e = ?",
                  "f = ?",
                  "result = a+b+c+d+e+f"
               ]

r = OP(b=1,d=3,e=45,f=9).result
print(r) # 65.0
f = OP(a=2,c=5,d=3,e=45,result=65).f
print(f) # 9.0


class ABCD(SmartFormula):
    def formulas(self) : return ["a=b+c*d","b=?","c=?","d=?"]

    @property
    def someProperty(self): return "Found it!"

abcd = ABCD(a=5,b=2,c=3)
print(abcd.d)            # 1.0
print(abcd.someProperty) # Found it!
print(abcd.moreToSolve)  # False
```

Comment: outstanding answer. I don't know if it's possible, but it would be interesting if somehow I can plug a equation like a=b+c*d and say, even if I only have a,b and c but missing d, it can still find out d from the equation. Without explicitly defining the equation for each variable in part.

Comment: just wanter to point out that in your classes, in case I would have to add additional properties to the class, I will not be able to access them, because your getattr is not checking for properties into self.

Comment: You can still access properties and variables of the class because `_getattr_` manages this automatically (as opposed to `__getattrib__` which doe indeed require extra work to return other properties).

Comment: See second EDIT for a formula based approach with partial term solver.

Comment: referring back to the additional properties problem, what I meant to say is that if you decorate with @property a method and you try to access it, you implementation will not be able to retrieve it because getattr is only checking the params, with is same as init values. I edited a fix for that, which was to check in self.__dict__ and self.__class__.__dict__

Comment: That's weird, I tested @property as well as self.precision from an instance and they worked fine.

Comment: again, outstanding, outstanding outstanding. I don't see how getter @property would work once you are overriding __getatter__ to look only in the params. I mean, as long as you are not checking the self.__class__.__dict__, you will no be able to access any of the getters. Just sayin'

Comment: See additional answer for yet more improvements to the SmartFormula class using a simple algebraic solver

Comment: what I meant with the @property decorator is that it is not accessible from your dictionaries like "weightLb":  lambda: self.someProperty, for example. This will not work. Sorry I forgot to mention this important detail

Answer (score 1):

Just precompute the missing values in `__init__` (and since you know what the 5 values are, be explicit rather than trying to compress the code using `kwargs`):

```
# Note: Make all 6 keyword-only arguments
def __init__(self, *, a=None, b=None, c=None, d=None, e=None, f=None):
     if a is None:
         a = b * c - d
     if c is None:
         c = e / f

     self.sum = a + b + c + d + e + f

def calculate(self):
    return self.sum
```

Answer (score 1):

**[New Answer to complement previous one]**

I felt my answer was getting too big so I'm adding this improved solution in a separate one.

This is a basic algebra solver to for simple equations that will output an assignment statement for a different term of the input equation:

For example:

```
solveFor("d","a=b+c/d") # --> 'd=c/(a-b)'
```

With this function, you can further improve the SmartFormula class by attempting to use algebra before reverting to Newton-Raphson.  This will provide more reliable results when the equation is simple enough for the solveFor() function.

The solveFor() function can solve the equation for any term that appears only once in the formula. It will "understand" the calculation as long as the components to solve are only related with basic operations (+, -, *, /, **). Any group in parentheses that does not contain the target term will be processed "as is" without being further interpreted.  This allows you to place complex functions/operators in parentheses so that other terms can be solved even in the presence of these special calculations.

```
import re
from itertools import accumulate

def findGroups(expression):
    levels = list(accumulate(int(c=="(")-int(c==")") for c in expression))
    groups = "".join([c,"\n"][lv==0] for c,lv in zip(expression,levels)).split("\n")
    groups = [ g+")" for g in groups if g ]
    return sorted(groups,key=len,reverse=True)

functionMap = [("sin","asin"),("cos","acos"),("tan","atan"),("log10","10**"),("exp","log")]
functionMap += [ (b,a) for a,b in functionMap ]

def solveFor(term,equation):
    equation = equation.replace(" ","").replace("**","†")
    termIn = re.compile(f"(^|\\W){term}($|\\W)")
    if len(termIn.findall(equation)) != 1: return None
    left,right = equation.split("=",1)
    if termIn.search(right): left,right = right,left

    groups = { f"#{i}#":group for i,group in enumerate(findGroups(left)) }
    for gid,group in groups.items(): left = left.replace(group,gid)
    termGroup = next((gid for gid,group in groups.items() if termIn.search(group)),"##" )

    def moveTerms(leftSide,rightSide,oper,invOper):
        keepLeft = None
        for i,x in enumerate(leftSide.split(oper)):
            if termGroup in x or termIn.search(x):
                keepLeft  = x; continue
            x = x or "0"
            if any(op in x for op in "+-*/"): x = "("+x+")"
            rightSide = invOper[i>0].replace("{r}",rightSide).replace("{x}",x)
        return keepLeft, rightSide

    def moveFunction(leftSide,rightSide,func,invFunc):
        fn = leftSide.split("#",1)[0]
        if fn.split(".")[-1] == func:
            return leftSide[len(fn):],fn.replace(func,invFunc)
        return leftSide,rightSide

    left,right = moveTerms(left,right,"+",["{r}-{x}"]*2)
    left,right = moveTerms(left,right,"-",["{x}-{r}","{r}+{x}"])  
    left,right = moveTerms(left,right,"*",["({r})/{x}"]*2)
    left,right = moveTerms(left,right,"/",["{x}/({r})","({r})*{x}"])  
    left,right = moveTerms(left,right,"†",["log({r})/log({x})","({r})†(1/{x})"])
    for func,invFunc in functionMap:
        left,right = moveFunction(left,right,func,f"{invFunc}({right})")
    for sqrFunc in ["math.sqrt","sqrt"]:
        left,right = moveFunction(left,right,sqrFunc,f"({right})**2")

    for gid,group in groups.items(): right = right.replace(gid,group)
    if left == termGroup:
        subEquation = groups[termGroup][1:-1]+"="+right
        return solveFor(term,subEquation)
    if left != term: return None
    solution = f"{left}={right}".replace("†","**")
    # expression clen-up
    solution = re.sub(r"(?<!\w)(0\-)","-",solution)
    solution = re.sub(r"1/\(1/(\w)\)",r"\g<1>",solution)
    solution = re.sub(r"\(\(([^\(]*)\)\)",r"(\g<1>)",solution)
    solution = re.sub(r"(?<!\w)\((\w*)\)",r"\g<1>",solution)
    return solution
```

Example Uses:

```
solveFor("x","y=(a+b)*x-(math.sin(1.5)/322)")   # 'x=(y+(math.sin(1.5)/322))/(a+b)'
solveFor("a","q=(a**2+b**2)*(c-d)**2")          # 'a=(q/(c-d)**2-b**2)**(1/2)'
solveFor("a","c=(a**2+b**2)**(1/2)")            # 'a=(c**2-b**2)**(1/2)'    
solveFor("a","x=((a+b)*c-d)*(23+y)")            # 'a=(x/(23+y)+d)/c-b'
sa = solveFor("a","y=-sin((x)-sqrt(a))")        # 'a=(x-asin(-y))**2'
sx = solveFor("x",sa)                           # 'x=a**(1/2)+asin(-y)'
sy = solveFor("y",sx)                           # 'y=-sin(x-a**(1/2))'
```

*Note that you can probably find much better algebra 'solvers' out there, this is just a simple/naive solution.*

Here is an improved version of the SmartFormula class that uses solveFor() to attempt an algebra solution before reverting to Newton-Raphson approximations:

```
class SmartFormula:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.params        = kwargs
        self.precision     = 0.000001
        self.maxIterations = 10000
        self._formulas     = [(f.split("=",1)[0].strip(),f) for f in self.formulas()]
        terms = set(term for _,f in self._formulas for term in re.findall(r"\w+\(?",f) )
        terms = [ term for term in terms if "(" not in term and not term.isdigit() ]
        self._formulas    += [ (term,f"{term}=solve('{term}')") for term in terms]
        self(**kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, name):       
        if name in self.params: return self.params[name]

    def __call__(self, **kwargs):
        self.params          = kwargs
        self.moreToSolve     = True
        self.params["solve"] = lambda n: self.autoSolve(n)
        self.resolve()
        return self.params.get(self._formulas[0][0],None)

    def resolve(self):
        while self.moreToSolve:
            self.moreToSolve = False
            for param,formula in self._formulas:
                if self.params.get(param,None) is not None: continue
                try: 
                    exec(formula,globals(),self.params)
                    if self.params.get(param,None) is not None:
                        self.moreToSolve = True
                except: pass

    def autoSolve(self, name):
        for resolver in [self.algebra, self.newtonRaphson]:
            for source,formula in self._formulas:
                if self.params.get(source,None) is None:
                    continue
                if not re.search(f"(^|\\W){name}($|\\W)",formula):
                    continue
                resolver(name,source,formula)
                if self.params.get(name,None) is not None:
                    return self.params[name]

    def algebra(self, name, source, formula):
        try:    exec(solveFor(name,formula),globals(),self.params)            
        except: pass

    def newtonRaphson(self, name, source,formula):
        simDict = self.params.copy()
        target  = self.params[source]
        value   = target
        for _ in range(self.maxIterations):                    
            simDict[name] = value
            try: exec(formula,globals(),simDict)
            except: break
            result        = simDict[source]
            resultDelta   = target-result
            if abs(resultDelta) < self.precision : 
                self.params[name] = round(value/self.precision/2)*self.precision*2
                return       
            value += value*resultDelta/result/2
```

This allowed the example class (BodyMassIndex) to avoid specification of the `"weightKg     = heightM**2*bmi"` calculation because the algebra solver can figure it out.  The improved class also eliminates the need to indicate auto-solving term names ("term = ?").

```
import math
class BodyMassIndex(SmartFormula):

    def formulas(self):
        return [
                 "bmi      = weightKg / (heightM**2)",
                 "heightM  = heightInches * 0.0254",
                 "weightKg = weightLb / 2.20462"
               ]

bmi = BodyMassIndex()
print("bmi",bmi(heightM=1.75,weightKg=130)) # 42.44897959183673
print("weight",bmi.weightLb)                # 286.6006 (130 Kg)

bmi(bmi=42.45,weightKg=130)
print("height",bmi.heightInches) # 68.8968097135968  (1.75 Meters)
```

For the original question, this is simple as can be:

```
class OP(SmartFormula):

    def formulas(self):
        return [
                  "result = a+b+c+d+e+f",
                  "a = b * c - d",
                  "c = e/f"
               ]

r = OP(b=1,d=3,e=45,f=9).result
print(r) # 65.0
f = OP(a=2,c=5,d=3,e=45,result=65).f
print(f) # 9.0
```

*Newton-Raphson was not used in any of these calculations because the algebra solves them in priority before trying the approximations*

Comment: Alain, this really helped me a lot. Would you write this in a git?

Comment: I placed it on GitHub.  Look for PythonAlgebra101

Comment: You are awesome